# ARKit or RealityKit – How can we detect a real world object?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, coreml

I need to detect a suitcase in AR and then estimate its size.

How can we achieve it using ARKit or RealityKit in iOS?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am very new to AR. I am able to detect planes with ARAnchor. Then I thought I can also detect real world object using ARObjectAnchor but could not succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

To detect a real-world object use the following code using `ARKit`/`SceneKit` classes:

```
import ARKit

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                 didAdd node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        
        if let _ = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {

            let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.25))
            node.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.delegate = self
        
        guard let obj = ARReferenceObject.referenceObjects(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", 
                                                                 bundle: nil)
        else { fatalError("See no reference object") }

        config.detectionObjects = obj

        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

You need to put in Xcode's `AR Resources` folder all needed [reference objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceobject).

A size of object is known in this case.

> Afterword

If you need a controlled `object detection` or `object recognition` features for different suitcases use CoreML or Vision frameworks that allow you use pre-trained `.mlmodel` (you can create it in `Apple Create ML` app or in Xcode Playground) with up to 10K images inside.

Comment: Your answer is helpful but it seems that we can only detect objects that we have already scanned. Is it possible tha i scan one suitcase and then detect some other suitcase. i think no right ?

Comment: Just a note about marrying computer vision with AR. Watch out for the fact the frames from ARKit always come through in a specific orientation and predictions from CoreML have the origin in the lower left. Eventually you end up with a point (center of prediction) you can then ray-cast into the scene. Getting that point correct for all device orientations is hard.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for might be what is called "semanticization of objects", which ARKit supports in a very limited fashion: [ARMeshClassification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armeshclassification)

If you enable `.sceneReconstruction` on your `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` (after checking if that function is actually supported by the respective device with `supportsSceneReconstruction(_:)`) ARKit is able to classify very simple objects like chairs, tables and walls, but (as far as I know) without supplying a resource for ARKit to reference, it won't be able to recognize a suitcase as an actual suitcase object out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is real-time recognition of suitcases in general--as opposed to some specific suitcase--then ARKit will not do what you want.

Apple's [CoreML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) framework could be used to build a suitcase recognition app. Here is some Apple sample code that demonstrates this using the [Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) (rather than ARKit) to do object recognition: [Recognizing Objects in Live Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture)

I don't have any advice on how you would jump from CoreML recognition to recognizing and measuring the suitcase's edges in two or three dimensions, but I imagine you would need to identify not only the object, but it's vertices (which also sounds like a machine learning task).  Once you had those, then you might be able to place them in 3D space and measure the distances between them, calculating height, width and depth of the suitcase.